# python exec, add staticmethod to class

Tags: python, class, exec, static-methods

In python I can do:

```
exec(code_string, globals(), some_object.__dict__)
```

to add a method to an object. Is it possible to add a static method to a class in some sort of similar fashion? Like:

```
exec(code_string, globals(), ClassName.__dict__)
```

So that I could then statically call the method:

```
ClassName.some_static_method()
```

What I'm trying to do is add new staticmethods during runtime given some python code defining the method. i.e. if I was given:

```
code_string = '''
@staticmethod
def test():
    return 'blah'
'''
```

how can I create and instantiate this into a class so that I could call it?

Hopefully I was clear enough, thank you!

**EDIT:**
working example of adding a function to an object:

```
class TestObject(object):
    pass

code_string = '''
def test():
return 'blah'
'''
t = TestObject()
exec(code_string, globals(), t.__dict__)
```

Comment: The first expression, following "In python I can do:" gives a `TypeError: 'dictproxy' object does not support item assignment` in any case

Comment: I can't get the formatting in this comment so I added it to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setattr()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)

```
>>> code_string = '''
... @staticmethod
... def test():
...     return 'returning blah'
... '''
>>>
>>> exec(code_string)

>>> test
<staticmethod object at 0x10fd25c58>

>>> class ClassName(object):
...     def instancemethod(self):
...             print "instancemethod!"
...
>>> setattr(ClassName, 'teststaticmethod', test)

>>> ClassName.teststaticmethod()
'returning blah'
>>>
```

[And here's an article on being safe with exec() and eval() in python.](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll use this tactic, though the only problem with it is that it requires me to provide the name for the function. I can think of a few ways to work with this though, thanks again!

Comment: I was wondering if that would be an issue for you. I'll give it some more thought!